# Push an object into an object's array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

So I am trying to push a new Item object into a ToDo object after it's creation. I cant seem to be able to add a new item to a todo after I make it.

Here are my two schemas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Item = new mongoose.Schema({
  ItemName : String,
  todo: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo'}
});
mongoose.model('Item', Item);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var ToDo = new mongoose.Schema({
  ToDoName : String,
  items: [ {item : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}}]
});
mongoose.model('ToDo', ToDo);
```

I am sure its something wrong with my app.post for creating items:

```
app.post('/todos/:todo_id/items', function(req, res, next) {

    Item.create({
        //_id : req.body.item_id,
        ItemName : req.body.ItemName,
        todoId : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, item) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the items after you create another
        Item.find(function(err, items) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(items);
        }); 

        item.save(function(err, item){
            if(err){ return next(err); }

        ToDo.items.push(item);
        ToDo.save(function(err, todo) {
            if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(item);
         });
        });

        }); 
    });
```

I have tried several different solutions and typically get the error: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined." All I really need this to do is add the new item to the items array of the current ToDo. If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance,

Quinn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is improper, you have multiple responses, none of them will ever execute except first one, expressjs will throw exception like *cannot modify sent headers*, as i understood, you want to create item, add it to todo, and get all items from that todo. Code below should help you

```
app.post('/todos/:todo_id/items', function(req, res, next) {

    Item.create({
        ItemName : req.body.ItemName,
        todoId : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, item) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else {
            //push to proper ToDo
            ToDo.update({_id: req.params.todo_id}, {$push: { items: item }}, function(updateError, updateResponse){
                if(updateError) {
                    res.send(updateError);
                } else {
                    //find all items that have exact todo_id
                    Item.find({todo: req.params.todo_id}, function(findError, foundItems) {
                        if(findError) {
                            res.send(findError)
                        } else {
                            res.json(foundItems);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver! This fixed my problem thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are trying to modify a mongoose document which is different from a JavaScript object. Append a .lean() to your find call to receive a regular JavaScript object.